# Adding HS2 SnakeGrid Projection to QGIS

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-3, proj

How do I add the HS2 Snake Grid Projection to QGIS?

I have the projection file `HS2TN15_NTv2.GSB` and I have added to the shared projections folder `C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\share\proj`.

I also know that the HS2 survey grid is on the ESPG:9300  .

I know from [the manual section 10.5.1](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_projections/working_with_projections.html#integrate-an-ntv2-transformation-in-qgis) that I also need to add a custom projection, and include the parameters, part of which is the file name. But, being right at the limit of my knowledge I have no clue as to what this might comprise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HS2 Survey Grid NTv2 User Guide specifies the following coordinate system parameters in WKT format:

```
PROJCS["HS2_Snake",
  GEOGCS["GCS_HS2SD",
    DATUM["D_HS2SD",
      SPHEROID["WGS_1984", 6378137.0, 298.257223563]],
      PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0],
      UNIT["Degree", 0.0174532925199433]],
  PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["False_Easting", 198873.0046],
    PARAMETER["False_Northing", 375064.3871],
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian", -1.5],
    PARAMETER["Scale_Factor", 1.0],
    PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin", 52.3],
    UNIT["Meter", 1.0]]
```

For the `proj` string, including the **nadgrids** it would be:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=52.3 +lon_0=-1.5 +k=1 +x_0=198873.0046 +y_0=375064.3871 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs  +nadgrids=HS2TN15_NTv2.gsb
```